# Problem with firebase authentification function error messages being all the same

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication

My issue is that I'm trying to build a sign in / sign up page for my flutter app but the `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)` function gives the save error.code whatever I do in terms of email password combination.

Here is the full code:

```
Future\<void\> \_signInWithEmailAndPassword(context) async {
try {_email = retrieve_email();

    
    
      await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
    
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');


    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      print(error.code);
      switch (error.code) {
        case 'invalid-email':
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Invalid Email'),
              content: Text('Please enter a valid email address.'),
              actions: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  child: Text('OK'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
          break;
        case 'wrong-password':
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Incorrect Password'),
              content: Text('The password you entered is incorrect.'),
              actions: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  child: Text('OK'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
          break;
        case 'user-not-found':
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text('User Not Found'),
              content: Text(
                  'The email address you entered does not belong to an existing user.'),
              actions: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  child: Text('OK'),
                ),
              ],
            ),


          );
          break;
        default:
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Sign In Error'),
              content: Text(
                  'An error occurred while signing in. Please try again later.'),
              actions: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  child: Text('OK'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
      }
    }

}
```

However, this is stated in the documentation of the function:

> A [FirebaseAuthException] maybe thrown with the following error code:
>
> invalid-email:
> Thrown if the email address is not valid.
> user-disabled:
> Thrown if the user corresponding to the given email has been disabled.
> user-not-found:
> Thrown if there is no user corresponding to the given email.
> wrong-password:
> Thrown if the password is invalid for the given email, or the account corresponding to the email does not have a password set.

The only error that works is the invalid-email one, the others which are user-not-found and wrong-password never appear. I always get the same INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS in all cases. Because of this I am unable to display the current message to the user and to navigate to the sign up page if the email doesn't exist. I even tried another method using `List list = await auth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(emailAddress);` Here is the full method:

```
// Returns true if email address is in use.
Future<bool> checkIfEmailInUse(String emailAddress) async {
  try {
    // Fetch sign-in methods for the email address
    print(emailAddress);

    List list = await auth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(emailAddress);

    print(list);
    // In case list is not empty
    if (list.isNotEmpty) {
      // Return true because there is an existing
      // user using the email address
      print("there is an existing user with this email !");
      return true;
    } else {
      // Return false because email adress is not in use
      return false;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle error
    // ...

    return false;
  }
}
```

I saw online that this would return me an empty list only if the email address did not belong to an existing user. But it returns me an empty list even if the email belongs to a user. The only thing that works is that if th email and password are both correct then the log in works but I can't deal with any other case.

Does anyone have an idea of why the first function always gives the same `error.code`, and then why for the second function the list is empty even if the email belongs to a user ?

Answer (score 1):

On project created since September 15 2023, Firebase's built-in [protection against email enumeration attacks](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection) is enabled by default. This changes the way some of the APIs respond, in order to protect your users from this sort of attack.

In your specific code the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` will no longer distinguish between a non-existent email and an existent email with a wrong password, as that is precisely the information that malicious users can use to look for email addresses (and then perform a more targeted attack on this).

You will either have to the more generic error messages, or [disable the protection against email enumeration attacks](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection#disable).

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank I would have had trouble finding this information on my own. For now I think I will just diable the protection because it is just the begging but for the other method: List list = await auth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(emailAddress); Do you know why it returns an empty list even if the email is one of my users'. This would enable me to propose signing in or signing up after the user enters his email.

Thank you again for your help !

Comment: `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` is another method that allows for email enumeration attacks, so it returns an empt list when you have protection for that attack enabled.

Comment: okay perfect thanks a lot! So what do you advise, for the beginning it should be fine the disable the protection? I wonder how big apps that use firebase  who want to enable the protection against those attacks do to manage authentification. I don't know if there would be an alternative. Maybe storing emails in the users firestorm collection.